# SharePoint 2013 Form Library version history

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, form, forms-library

InfoPath form library version history is not showing the modified fields. It just displays a link to the particular version of the InfoPath form with modified by and modified date details.

if these are limitations from Infopath form or SharePoint product end or is there any configuration settings available in central admin site for this.

Is there any possibility to capture all the modified fields for a Form library items without any code (I mean only using OOTB feature / settings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint built in feature for tracking the versions, but its for the overall form because the data submitted to SharePoint Library will be in XML format, so there is no functionality to find changes of text within a XML.

Try with the following methods, which I have implemented few years ago,

1. Make the InfoPath to be submitted to custom form library.
2. Before publishing the form, select the Property Promotion columns for which you need to track the versions.
3. Once you have published the form, you can see the form library with the promoted columns, now created new calculated column for each promotion columns, for ex: If you have a column as "Name", then create a new calculated column as "NameforVersion' which should get the value from "Name" column, do the same for all other promotion columns.
4. Now you can submit a new form in the library and then edit the form.
5. After editing the form, the newly added calculated columns will have the edited values. You can remove the newly added caculated columns from the view, if you want.
6. Now if you check the version, you can see list of fields which were changed during each version.

This is a work around to do your requirement without code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried using calculated column, but multi line of text and multiselection listbox cannot be added to calculated column, how can i achieve for those column also

Comment: Follow the below link to reference "multi line of text" in your calculated column. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/taming-the-elusive-_e2_80_9ccalculated-column_e2_80_9d-referencing-multiple-lines-of-text-column.aspx

Comment: Is your list having columns of type "multiselection listbox", if so, is it choice fields.?

Comment: Anyway Karthik....adding calculated column for every field will add complexity...becoz i do have 100 columns in infopath form...creating 100 calculated column for 100 infopath form column is a massive one...no client will accept this

Comment: Fine, then this approach will not be useful for you, kindly provide precise data in your questions, so that we will be guided in the right way :)

Comment: Thanks for the info Karthik...i have to confirm with the limitations in sharepoint..Your post helped me...